# How Do I Populate Textbox and Checkboxes With Combobox selection from anothe database in vb

Tags: vb.net

Please i want to the textboxes and other checkboxes in the payroll form to get data from the employee registration database when i select the employee name in the employee combobox please any idea on how i can do that. below is what i tried but it is not working.........

```
Private Sub employeenamecmbbx_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles employeenamecmbbx.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
        con.Open()
        Dim ct As String = "select employeename,basicsalary,cashbenefits,allowances,vehiclefueldriver,vehiclefuel,vehicleonly,fuelonly,accomodationwithfurnishing  m ,accomodationonly,sharedaccomodation from employeeregistration where employeename=@find"

        cmd = New OleDbCommand(ct)
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@find", OleDbType.VarChar, 30, "employeename"))
        cmd.Parameters("@find").Value = Trim(employeenamecmbbx.Text)
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If rdr.Read Then
            Allowances.Text = Trim(rdr.GetString(0))
            BasicSalary.Text = Trim(rdr.GetInt32(1))
            CashBenefits.Text = Trim(rdr.GetString(2))
            Vehicle_Fuel_DriverCheckBox.Checked = Trim(rdr.GetString(3))
            Vehicle_FuelCheckBox.CheckState = Trim(rdr.GetString(4))
            VehicleOnlyCheckBox.CheckState = Trim(rdr.GetString(5))
            FuelOnlyCheckBox.CheckState = Trim(rdr.GetString(6))
            AccomodationOnlyCheckBox.CheckState = Trim(rdr.GetString(7))
            AccomodationWithFurnishingCheckBox.CheckState = Trim(rdr.GetString(8))
            Shared_AccomodationCheckBox.CheckState = Trim(rdr.GetString(9))
            MarriageReponsibilityCheckBox.CheckState = Trim(rdr.GetString(10))
            DisabledCheckBox.CheckState = Trim(rdr.GetString(11))
            OldAgeCheckBox.CheckState = Trim(rdr.GetString(12))
            ChildEducationCheckBox.CheckState = Trim(rdr.GetString(13))
            AgeDependantCheckBox.CheckState = Trim(rdr.GetString(14))
            TrainingCostCheckBox.CheckState = Trim(rdr.GetString(15))
            Tier3ContributionCheckBox.CheckState = Trim(rdr.GetString(16))

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

    If Not rdr Is Nothing Then
        rdr.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

this is wat i did but when i try nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I think first you need to check to see if the `rdr.hasRows()` before trying to read them. This may cause the exception to occur.

Are you getting an error message or is it just not putting anything into the checkboxes and textboxes?

Comment: i get and error that says no given value for one or more parameters

Comment: In that case it is probably happening when there is nothing in the `employeenamecmbbx.Text` field. I would do a check to make sure there is something in there before trying to retrieve data.

Comment: thank you now i have it done but the problem now says "specified cast not valid" and this is the code below can u please tell me what the issue is...

Comment: I think your getting the cast error from the `Vehicle_Fuel_DriverCheckBox.Checked = Trim(rdr.GetString(3))` all of the fields that are checkboxes you can't directly cast from string to Boolean value. You will need to either wrap them in a `CBool()` which would be `Vehicle_Fuel_DriverCheckBox.Checked = CBool(Trim(rdr.GetString(3)))`, which can work as long as there is something there or make a function that will return the correct Boolean for the data that is coming back form the database.